# inserting data from list to DB

Tags: silverlight-4.0

i have an list like this now i need  to insert data  from the list  to DB (sql server 2005).

how can i iterate through list   1 by 1 record  and insert them  to DB

public class Users

{

```
public string Name { get; set; }  

public int Age { get; set; }  

public string Gender { get; set; }  

public string Country { get; set; }
```

}

public MainPage()

{

InitializeComponent();

List myList = new List

{

new Users{ Name="Hiro Nakamura", Gender="M", Age=24, Country="Japan"},

new Users{ Name="Mohinder Suresh",Gender="M", Age=26, Country="India"},

new Users{ Name="Claire Bennette", Gender="F",Age=19, Country="USA"},

new Users{ Name="Matt Parkman", Gender="M",Age=30, Country="USA"},

new Users{ Name="Nathan Patrelli", Gender="M",Age=30, Country="USA"},

new Users{ Name="Peter Patrelli", Gender="M",Age=26, Country="USA"},

new Users{ Name="Mica", Age=12, Gender="M",Country="USA"},

new Users{ Name="Linderman", Gender="M",Age=56, Country="USA"},

new Users{ Name="Ando", Age=24, Gender="M",Country="Japan"},

new Users{ Name="Maya", Age=24, Gender="M",Country="Mexico"},

new Users{ Name="Niki Sanders", Gender="F",Age=26, Country="USA"},

new Users{ Name="Angela Patrelli", Gender="F",Age=26, Country="USA"},

};

```
  MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = myList;
```

}

any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run a loop on the list 1 item at a time and for each item retrieve all the information from that one entry and parse it into a sql statement and run it against the DB.

Something like:

```
for i = 0 to listsize-1
  {
    get ith item;
    parse item into a sql insert statement;
    run the sql statement on the database;
  }
```